# Max 2-sat and clause size

Tags: combinatorics, logic, computational-complexity

I've seen that Max 2-Sat is NP-complete, are there instances in which every clause has exactly $2$ variables which are $NP$-complete? Or do all such instance need to contain a clause of exactly 1 variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that no instance itself is NP-complete. I will reformulate your question in a way that makes sense, hopefully capturing what you meant to ask.

Let *Strict Max 2-SAT* be the problem whose instances are those in Max 2-SAT where all clauses have 2 variables. The question is whether Strict Max 2-SAT is NP-hard.

We can reduce Max 2-SAT to Strict Max 2-SAT, which means that Max 2-SAT's NP-hardness implies Strict Max 2-SAT is also NP-hard, as follows. Let $x$ be an instance of Max 2-SAT. We will replace each clause of $x$ consisting of one variable with two clauses consisting of two variables; call this new instance $y$, which is an instance of Strict Max 2-SAT. This replacement will be such that a maximum assignment to $x$ corresponds in a simple way to a maximum assignment to $y$. Therefore solving $y$ gives a solution to $x$, completing the reduction.

Consider a clause of $x$ that has just one variable, say $(u)$ (if the clause consists of a negated variable then let $u$ be the negated variable). We introduce a new variable, say $v$, and replace $(u)$ by $(u \lor v) \land (u \lor \neg v)$. Note that when $u$ is true then both clauses in the replacement can be made true but when $u$ is false, at most one clause in the replacement can be made true. So fixing the value of $u$, the replacement's maximum satisfiability is one greater than the original clause's satisfiability. Therefore if $n$ is the number of single-variable clauses in $x$, $y$'s maximum satisfiability is $x$'s maximum satisfiability $+ n$.

Comment: There is something i'm not sure about with your constrcution, how do we avoid the following type of problem. Imagine that in the instance $x$ we split the clauses into two sets $X$ and $Y$, the first set $X$ contains  clauses which contain two variables and the set $Y$ clauses which contain just one. (continued)

Comment: Then suppose we have two assignments 1 and 2 to the variables in $x$ in the first $7$ clauses are satisfied in $X$ and $3$ in $Y$ (10 in total) and in the second $8$ clauses are satisfied in $X$ and non in $Y$. Then it follows with your reduction $y$ of strict Max 2-sat that we can satisfy $8+|Y|$ clauses in $y$ by setting all dummy variables equal to TRUE and following the second assignment of variables in x, which is larger than the $7+|Y|$ from the first assignment in $x$, however this doesn't mean that 8 is a maximum for $x$ because we can choose an assignment to satisfy $10$ clauses.

Comment: I think you misunderstand (or maybe I do?). Let assignments $1'$ and $2'$ be the same as 1 and 2 but with all dummy variables of $y$ set to true. Then $1'$ satisfies 7 clauses in $X$ and 3 in $Y$ and $2'$ satisfies 8 in $X$ and 0 in $Y$. That is because if we change a clause in $Y$ from $u$ to $u \land v$ where $v$ is a dummy variable, then in an assignment where $v$ is true, the clause reduces to $u$.

Comment: wait it should be $u \lor v$ so that's where the confusion is

Comment: Ah, you are right, my apologies. Things are a bit more complex than I thought. I'll try to work this out.

Comment: I came up with a new reduction that (hopefully) works.

Answer (score 0):

If a single 2-SAT clause contains the same variable twice, then either both literals are equal (in which there is only one way to set the variable, which reduces the 2-SAT formula), or one literal is the negation of the other, in which case any way you set the variable will satisfy that clause and thus that clause can be deleted. So yes, in general, you can assume that in a general Max 2-SAT problem, that every clause involves two different variables in some form (negated or not, although there may be multiple clauses that involve a certain variable or its negation).

Comment: Ahh ok what about if i specify that the underlying variables in each clause must be different? So i cannot have $x$ and $x'$? or $x$ twice?

Comment: But this is *max* 2-SAT, where not all clauses need be satisfied. So a contradictory clause can be deleted but a clause with one variable can't necessarily.